# I have passed a object in jsp. I want to retain the object properties along with the updated properties when the jsp hits another action

Tags: spring-mvc

I am just learning spring MVC.
I have passed a object named emp of class `Employee` using    `model.addAttribute("emp",emp);` to a jsp page. I have used the same modelAttribute in form attribute of jsp as:

```
 <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="emp" id="emp" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/AcceptIncrementDecrementPayroll">
```

So the fields with matching are displayed and allowed to update. Suppose Employee has firstName and salary. The salary is displayed in a text box and is editable. So I need the new salary value in the text field along with the other properties like firstName as an object of the employee class.
These are the controllers:

This is the first controller where i am setting the model attribute to Employee object emp.

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewIncDecPay")
public String ViewIncrDecrPayroll(HttpServletRequest req,Model model) 
{
    List<Employee> empList=this.employeeDaoImpl.getCurrentCTC(staffId);
    System.out.println("empList has: "+empList.toString());
    List<IncrementDecrementPayroll>  empRequestList=this.employeeDaoImpl.getExpectedCTC(staffId);
    System.out.println("empRequestList has: "+empRequestList.toString());
    int count=0;

    for(Employee emp:empList){//empList has only one object as it is fetched based on a criteria
        System.out.println(count+"in List");
        model.addAttribute("emp", emp);
    }

    model.addAttribute("incrementDecrement", empRequestList);
    return "ViewIncrementDecrementPayroll";
}
```

This is the jsp page Form declaration

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="emp" id="emp" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/AcceptIncrementDecrementPayroll">
    <form:input path="salary" type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="basicMonthly"  value=""/>
</form>
```

This is the controller function that is being hit by the jsp page

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value="/AcceptIncrementDecrementPayroll")
public void acceptIncrement(HttpServletRequest req,Model model,@ModelAttribute("Employee")Employee emp){

    System.out.println("in accept payroll");
    String employeeName=emp.getFirstName();//this gives me null as all the properties are lost
    System.out.println("returned after jsp: name is: "+employeeName);

}
```

Above in `@ModelAttribute` I have declared again the object and there it looses it properties, but I don't know how to call the same object again. Thanks for any suggestion!